# Store Func<T> delegates

Tags: c#, casting, func

I am stuck on a problem. I found out that there is no implicit conversion from `Func<int>` to `Func<object>` and then especially not from generic `Func<T>`. I sort of understand why there is no conversion. But I still need to store any functions like the following:

```cs
static Dictionary<int, Func<int, object>> funcs = new Dictionary<int, Func<int, object>>();
public static void SetFunction<T>(Func<int, T> f)
{
    funcs[42] = f;
}

public static void Main()
{
    SetFunction(x => 42);
    SetFunction(x => "42");
    SetFunction(x => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

Is there any way around to store these functions? I don't want to use `dynamic`.
Also I need to keep original functions. To call them multiple times.

Comment: `Func<TResult>` has  covariant return type, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is invariant

Comment: `public static void SetFunction(Func<object> f) {...}`

Comment: @HansPassant, that is the other option, if you're allowed to change the API.

Comment: I can't change API. I have to keep Generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build an answer based on yours. Especially Blindy's.
I needed some reasoning but you enlightened me enough to build it.

```
static Dictionary<int, Func<object>> funcs = new Dictionary<int, Func<object>>();
static Random rnd = new Random();
public static void SetFunction<T>(int index, Func<Random, T> f)
{
    funcs[index] = () => (object)f(rnd);
}

public static void Main()
{
    SetFunction(41, x => x.NextDouble());
    SetFunction(42, x => x.Next());
    SetFunction(43, _ => "HW");
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[41]());
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[41]());
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[42]());
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[42]());
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[43]());
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[43]());
}
```

Output:

```
0.6657498062894446
0.5739200415899605
1762534382
1301357548
HW
HW
```

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't use `dynamic` anyway, it's not what it's for. Instead of thinking about casting, simply add another layer to your function:

```
public static void SetFunction<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    funcs[42] = () => (object)f();
}
```

Comment: No, I don't. Feel free to trace it out if you want.

Comment: `dynamic` would work in `void SetFunction(Func<int, dynamic> f) { funcs[42] = f; }` although there's little point to that over `Func<int, object>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably avoid using generics altogether.

```
static Dictionary<int, Func<object>> funcs = new Dictionary<int, Func<object>>();

public static void SetFunction(Func<object> f)
{
    funcs[42] = f;
}

public static void Main()
{
    SetFunction(() => 42);
    SetFunction(() => "42");
    SetFunction(() => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```